# how to set first image into imageView from ArrayList<string>

Tags: java, android

I am getting this array of images using Pix image picker library, I just want to display the first image from an array into image view.no idea how to do it. here is my code

```
public void uploadImages(View view) {
   Pix.start(Upload_ad.this,
            100,
            10);

}
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
             ArrayList<String> returnValue = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Pix.IMAGE_RESULTS);

           for (String path: returnValue)
            {

                String base64 = getBase64FromFile(path);
                encodedImageList.add(base64);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set base64 string from your encoded list as below

```
if (encodedImageList != null) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(0), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
    yourimageview.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
}
```

Comment: ok for now working for both but app crashes when i select single picture after applying this code.
 
        if (encodedImageList.get(1) != null) {

            //2nd image
            byte[] decodedString2 = Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(1), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString2, 0, decodedString2.length);
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(decodedByte2);
        }

Comment: debug and check if your `encodedImageList` has elements that you are accessing.

Comment: it has element in encodedImageList.get(1) ,and 2nd image also set to 2nd image view but the problem occurs when i select single image.

Comment: It would be good if you can post it as separate question with code and error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage somehow by:

```
ArrayList<String> returnValue = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Pix.IMAGE_RESULTS);
if(returnValue != null && !returnValue.isEmpty()) {
    String firstImage = returnValue.get(0);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(firstImage)) {
        // here you will find first-image
    }
}
```